# Installing herouku on ubuntu 10.10

Tags: ubuntu, heroku, rubygems

I am getting the following error while trying to install heroku.

```
arun@laptop:~/apps/pm$ sudo gem install heroku
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing heroku:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/bin/ruby1.8 extconf.rb
extconf.rb:1:in `require': no such file to load -- mkmf (LoadError)
    from extconf.rb:1


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.4.6 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.4.6/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
arun@laptop:~/apps/pm$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks a lot like [this issue](http://blogs.law.harvard.edu/hoanga/2006/10/27/fixing-mkmf-load-error-ruby-in-ubuntu/).

This got solved with

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.8-dev
```

Comment: i was able to install heroku.. but none of the heroku commands are working.   "heroku: command not found"

Comment: You need to add it to the path to be able to run it. In my case it was in /var/lib/gems/1.8/bin